# Unable to show a recycler bar

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, runtime-error, searchview

I have put a search bar on the homescreen. To do this recyclerView needs to be only after a search, which I haven't marked as hidden in the code, but I don't know why it's not showing. Also, I need to make it only visible when searching, so that my other buttons stay where they are.

Adapter class:

```
package com.jhc.ygc;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<SearchItems> results;

    public MyAdapter(List<SearchItems> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
    
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_search, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        SearchItems item = results.get(position);
        holder.nameTextView.setText(item.getName());
    
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Perform action when the item is clicked
                // You can access the selected item using the position parameter
                SearchItems selectedItem = results.get(position);
                String selectedName = selectedItem.getName();
    
                // Call your desired method or perform the necessary action with the selected item
                performAction(selectedItem);
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return results.size();
    }
    
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nameTextView;
    
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        }
    }
    
    private void performAction(SearchItems item) {
        // Implement your desired action here
        // This method will be called when an item is clicked
        String link = item.getLink();
        Character type = item.getType();
        switch (type) {
            case 'v':
                // Video
                // Add your video action here
                break;
            case 'a':
                // Audio
                // Add your audio action here
                break;
            case 'q':
                // Quiz
                // Add your quiz action here
                break;
            case 'e':
                // Ebook
                // Add your ebook action here
                break;
            default:
                // Error or fallback action
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Database class:

```
package com.jhc.ygc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database {
    private List<SearchItems> myObjects;

    public Database() {
        myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        // Add objects to the database
        //Grade 6 Video
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 6 Science", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=6&subject=science",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 6 Maths", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=6&subject=maths",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 6 Tamil", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=6&subject=tamil",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 6 English", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=6&subject=english",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 6 History", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=6&subject=history",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 6 ICT", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=6&subject=ict",'v'));
        //Grade 7 Video
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 7 Science", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=7&subject=science",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 7 Maths", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=7&subject=maths",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 7 Tamil", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=7&subject=tamil",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 7 English", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=7&subject=english",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 7 History", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=7&subject=history",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 7 ICT", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=7&subject=ict",'v'));
        //Grade 8 Video
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 8 Science", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=8&subject=science",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 8 Maths", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=8&subject=maths",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 8 Tamil", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=8&subject=tamil",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 8 English", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=8&subject=english",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 8 History", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=8&subject=history",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 8 ICT", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=8&subject=ict",'v'));
        //Grade 9 Video
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 9 Science", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=9&subject=science",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 9 Maths", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=9&subject=maths",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 9 Tamil", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=9&subject=tamil",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 9 English", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=9&subject=english",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 9 History", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=9&subject=history",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 9 ICT", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=9&subject=ict",'v'));
        //Grade 10 Video
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 10 Science", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=10&subject=science",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 10 Maths", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=10&subject=maths",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 10 Tamil", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=10&subject=tamil",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 10 English", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=10&subject=english",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 10 History", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=10&subject=history",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 10 ICT", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=10&subject=ict",'v'));
        //Grade 11 Video
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 11 Science", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=11&subject=science",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 11 Maths", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=11&subject=maths",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 11 Tamil", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=11&subject=tamil",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 11 English", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=11&subject=english",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 11 History", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=11&subject=history",'v'));
        myObjects.add(new SearchItems("Grade 11 ICT", "file:///android_asset/interactive-video.html?grade=11&subject=ict",'v'));
    }

    public List<SearchItems> searchObjects(String query) {
        List<SearchItems> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SearchItems object : myObjects) {
            if (object.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                results.add(object);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

SearchItems Class:

```
package com.jhc.ygc;

public class SearchItems {
    private String name;
    private String link;
    private Character type; // AudioBook = a,Video = v, quiz=q,ebook=e (ONLY a,v,q,e)

    public SearchItems(String name, String link,Character type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.link = link;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public Character getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

item_search.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Part of activity_main.xml:

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/search"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

I tried to make many changes like LinearLayout manager, many suggestions in Stackoverflow and ChatGPT, but nothing worked.

UPDATE: I also have one as home_fragment.java. If it's in home fragment do I need to transfer code from MainActivity.java to home_fragment.java ?

Comment: UPDATE: I also have one as home_fragment.java. it's in home fragment so DO I need to transfer code from MainActivity.java to home_fragment.java

Answer (score 0):

In your RecyclerView has a fixed height (android:layout_height="200dp") in your XML layout and its visibility is set to visible by default. To make RecyclerView visible only during search, you can dynamically control its visibility in your activity depending on the search state.